# JSON crashes on simple string if there are spaces

Tags: java, android, json, gson

**The question is about JsonElement. That is the value of a key in Json. Hence a string is allowed. Seems though without a space**

Why does the following line gives JSON syntax exception?

```
new JsonParser().parse("Nexus 6")
```

Exception stack trace:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $
                                                                 at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
                                                                 at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
```

**Update:**
What I am interested in, is converting a string to a JsonElement

**Update:**
Why does this work?

```
new JsonParser().parse("Blah");
```

**Update 3:**
This also works:

```
new JsonParser().parse("Nexus_6")
```

Comment: "Nexus 6" is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain: It is a string. Why is it not valid?

Comment: If you take a lookt at: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 under 13. there is a similar example to what the OP has, i think it actually is valid JSON

Comment: `Nexus 6` is not a valid JSON string because it doesn't conform to the syntax of JSON. See http://json.org/

Comment: To downvoters and votes to close. Why the last example are parsed succesfully?

Comment: @StarterPack Where under [13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-13) do you see that? `"Hello world!"` is a quoted string, and `true` is one of only three allowed keywords. `Nexus 6` is not. Neither is `Blah`. A strict JSON parser should reject both of those. --- Note that `parse("Nexus 6")` is parsing the text `Nexus 6`, not `"Nexus 6"`. To parse `"Nexus 6"`, the code would have to be `parse("\"Nexus 6\"")`.

Comment: @Jim *FYI:* "OP" means "Original Poster", which means *you*. You didn't update the OP, you updated the question.

Comment: @Andreas yes i have realized that now, btw OP can also mean original post ;)

Comment: @Andreas:OP - Original Post

Comment: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420): **OP** *See: Original Poster*

Comment: @Andreas:The result of the parsing is a JsonElement. That is the value of a key in Json. Hence why is it invalid?

Comment: @Jim It's invalid because it doesn't adhere to the JSON syntax. Did you even look at the easy to read syntax diagrams at http://json.org/, that I posted link to earlier?

Comment: @Andreas: Yes I did. I think we are talking about different things. How can I create a **value** of a valid json that is represented by a String? That is what I was trying to do using a JsonElement. If I use a JsonPrimitive that code works with a space

Comment: @Jim What **value** do you want? "A *string* in double quotes, or a *number*, or `true` or `false` or `null`, or an *object* or an *array*"? (That was a quote of the definition of **value** from http://json.org/). If you want a *string* with the text `Nexus 6`, see [answer by StarterPack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42481768/5221149), or [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481228/json-crashes-on-simple-string-if-there-are-spaces?noredirect=1#comment72103151_42481228). Either clarify what you want, or read the comments/answers you already got. Preferably both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that your string value does not begin and end with quotation marks as described in [RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) under number 7 "Strings".

So something like this: `new JsonParser().parse("\"Nexus 6\"")` should work.

Comment: Just for the record also `new JsonPrimitive` also works